# Why do my download speeds drastically vary during a download?

Tags: download

I watch the download speed rise and fall like waves in a storm. At night, during low bandwidth usage I have achieve speeds as high as 3.23 M/sec but the watch them decline to 250 K/sec. and then climb back up. Over and over. During the day my best is around 1.67 M/sec with lows into the 65 K/sec. On top of this, why does a download need to slow down when approaching the end of the download? It's not like a multi-hundred ton train needing to decrease speed as it approaches the station.

Comment: Are you measuring download speed using some kind of clustering downloader like torrent programs? If so, it's based on the availability of the data you need. It slows down at the end for the same reason it takes collectors a long time to get the last few things they need -- the ones they still need will be the rarest ones.

Answer (score 4):

Your download/upload speed depends on a lot of things.
For example:

- Your router
- Number of connections
- The bandwidth usage of other people in your house/street sharing your cable
- If you are on the same copper as the phones, (ADSL) neghbours speaking on the phone will effect it

  Then the people you are exchanging data with are having the same thing happening to their connection. So no wonder it's fluctuating.